# Upvoting comments in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue does not actually upvote the comment

Tags: bug, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts, comment-votes

[image]

I've tried clicking it with both my mouse and my track pad or on a phone but it really doesn't work, as it doesn't show that the comment has any score at all when I open the post in a new tab.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this - works for me. I can upvote a comment in the review queue, then click the "link" button and see the upvote.

Comment: No repro on FireFox 35.0, WinXP SP3, though I doubt it's related.

Comment: No repro here either. Works just fine.

Comment: But based on the upvotes you would think more people have seen this...

Comment: Sockpuppets @rene

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but it works fine now. I swear it was bugged ten hours ago... [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)